# backbone js sort my contact list

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js

i have this code to get a list of my facebook contacts.How can i sort the list with my online contacts first.I checked within the peopleViewPerson if a contact is online but i dont know how to achieve this, i tried with the js function sort() but it gives no result on my list.

```
var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
className: 'peopleView',
initialize: function() {
  this.people = Hula.user.get("people");

this.people.on('add', this.addPerson, this);
  this.people.on('remove', this.render, this);
  $(".nav_item").removeClass("nav_item_s");
  $("#people_nav").addClass("nav_item_s");
},
render: function(){
    this.$el.empty();
    var header = $('<div id="people_header">');
    var title = $('<div class="t34 title">');
    title.html("Friends");
    header.append(title); 
    this.$el.append(header);
    var addOption = $('<div id="people_add_option">');
    var addInput = '<div id="addp"><div id="people_add_input_h"><form id="add_person_input_form" ><input id="add_person_input" name="s" type="text" value="Enter Hularing ID..." ></input></form></div></div>';
    addOption.html(addInput);
    this.$el.append(addOption);
    var list = $('<div id="people_list" >');
    this.$el.append(list);
    this.people.each(this.addPerson, this);
    list.sort();

    return this;
},
addPerson: function(person){
    var view = new PeopleViewPerson({model: person});
    this.$("#people_list").prepend(view.render().$el);

},
events: {
    'keypress #add_person_input': 'addNewPerson',
},
addNewPerson: function(e){
    var ID = $('#add_person_input').val();
    if(ID !=="Enter Hularing ID..."){
        if(e.which == 13) {
            if(validate(ID)){
                Hula.subscribe(ID);
                 this.$('#add_person_input').val("")
                 $("#add_person_input_form")[0].reset();
                $('#add_person_input').blur().focus();                   
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
});

var PeopleViewPerson = Backbone.View.extend({
className: 'friend_holder',
initialize: function() {
    $(this.el).attr('id', jid_to_id(this.model.get("jid")));
    this.model.on('all', this.render, this);
    this.model.get('conversation').get('messages').on('add', this.onNewMessage, this);
},
render: function() {
    var img = $('<div class="friend_img_h">');
    if(this.pic() == null){
        if(this.online() === true){
                img.html('<img src="farax/img/default.png" style="border:4px solid green;" />');
        } else {
                img.html('<img src="farax/img/default.png" style="border:4px solid white;" />');
        }            
    } else {
        var img_src = 'data:'+this.picType()+';base64,'+this.pic();
        if(this.online() === true){
                img.html('<img src="'+img_src+'" style="border:4px solid green;" height="50" width="50"/>')
        } else {
                img.html('<img src="'+img_src+'" style="border:4px solid white;" height="50" width="50"/>')
        }
    } 
    var info_h = $('<div class="friend_info_h">');
    var person_name = $('<div class="friend_name">');
    person_name.html(this.name());
    var line2 = $('<div class="friend_line2">');
    var status = this.status();
    line2.html(status);
    var option_h = $('<div class="friend_option_h">');
    option_h.html('<div class="msg_person_icon" ></div>');
    // CONTACT INFO DIV.
    var option_h1 = $('<div class="friend_option_h1">');
    // CONTACT INFO IMAGE IN CSS FILE.
    option_h1.html('<div class="msg_person_icon1"></div>');
    // CONTACT FACEBOOK TIJDLIJN.
    var option_h2 = $('<div class="friend_option_h2">');
    // CONTACT FACEBOOK TIJDLIJN IMAGE IN CSS FILE.
    option_h2.html('<div class="msg_person_icon2"></div>');
    var option_h3 = $('<div class="friend_option_h3">');
    option_h3.html('<div class="msg_person_icon3"></div>');
    // HUIDIG CONTACT NAAM.
    var naam = this.name();
    // MET HET REGISTREREN VAN NIEUWE GEBRUIKERS WORDT DE GEBRUIKERSNAAM Robert0Ilmer DUS ZET IK BIJ DE CONTACT 
    // NAAM EEN 0 OP DE PLAATS VAN DE SPATIE OM ZE HETZELFDE TE MAKEN.
    var naam1 = naam.replace(" ","0");
    var temp = "";
    // TEMP IS OM HET ARRAY ITEM OP TE SLAAN ALS DE NAAM NIET OVEREENKOMT, DIT IS DE IMAGE URL DIE STAAT VOOR 
    // DE NAAM DUS OP DIE MANIER HEB IK DE IMAGE URL AL OPGESLAGEN IN TEMP EN KAN IK HET GEBRUIKEN ALS DE NAAM
    // GEVONDEN IS.
    javaScript_array.forEach( function (arrayItem, index){
            var x = arrayItem;
            // VERGELIJK DE NAAM UIT DE DATABASE MET DE NAAM IN DE JAVASCRIPT ARRAY GEDEFINIEERD IN 
            // ../HU1/INDEX.PHP
            if(naam1 === arrayItem){
                        // VOOR DEBUGGING 
                        // alert(index + ': ' + x);               
                        option_h3.html('<div class="msg_person_icon3"><img src="'+ temp +
                                       '" width="35" height="35"/></div>');
            }     
            temp = x;    
    });     
    if(this.ask()== "subscribe"){
        line2.prepend('<span class="pending_out">Request pending.</span>');
    }
    if(this.pending()){
        line2.prepend('<span class="pending_in">Pending authorisation!</span>');
    }
    info_h.append(person_name).append(line2);
    this.$el.html(img);
    this.$el.append(info_h);
    this.$el.append(option_h);      
    this.$el.append(option_h1);             
    this.$el.append(option_h2);             
    this.$el.append(option_h3);             
    return this;
},
jid: function() { return this.model.get('jid');},
name: function() { return this.model.get('name'); },
status: function() { return this.model.get('status'); },
pic: function() { return this.model.get('picture').pic; },
picType: function() { return this.model.get('picture').picType; },
ask: function() { return this.model.get('ask'); },
subscription: function() { return this.model.get('subscription'); },
pending: function() { return this.model.get('pending'); },
online: function() { return this.model.get('online'); },
events: {
    'click .friend_img_h': 'loadPerson',
    'click .msg_person_icon1': 'fbInfo', 
    'click .msg_person_icon': 'messagePerson' 
},
fbInfo: function(){ 
    // DE STRING idsd BEVAT NU -11107049625@chat.facebook.com
    var idsd = this.jid();
    // VOOR DEBUGGING
    // alert(idsd);
    // ZOEK NAAR  @chat.facebook.com EN VERVANG HET MET NIKS DUS VERWIJDER HET.
    var id1 = idsd.replace("@chat.facebook.com","");
    // alert(id1);
    // NU BEVAT id1 DIT   -11107049625 DUS ZOEKEN WE NAAR - EN VERWIJDEREN HET.
    var id2 = id1.replace("-","");
    // alert(id2);
    // NU BEVAT id2 HET ID NUMMER VAN HET AANGEKLIKTE CONTACT EN KUNNEN WE DE .
    myFunction(id2);
},
loadPerson: function(){ 
    Hula.screen.person.render(this.model);
},
messagePerson: function(){
    Hula.screen.conversation.render(this.model);
},
onAll: function(person){
},
onNewMessage: function(message){
    $('#people_list #'+jid_to_id(this.jid())+' .friend_line2').html(message.get("message"));
},
OnStatusChange: function(change){
    $("#people_list #"+id_to_jid(this.jid())).html(this.status().toString());
}    
});
```

i have this collection where i put a comparator but it is not sorting my list

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({    
defaults: {
    jid : null,
    name : null, 
    online: false, 
    status : null, 
    picture : { 
        pic : null, 
        picType : null
    },
    subscription: 'none',
    ask: null, 
    pending: false, 
    counter: { messages:0, stuff:0 },
    conversation: null
},
initialize: function(){
    this.set('conversation', new Conversation());   
  this.sortVar = 'name';    
  },
comparator: function( collection ){
  var that = this;
  return( collection.get( that.sortVar ) );
},
updateName: function(name){this.set("name", name);},
updateOnline: function(online){this.set("online", online);},
updatePicture: function(picture){ this.set("picture", picture);},
updateSubscription: function(subscription){this.set("subscription", subscription) ;},
updateAsk: function(ask){this.set("ask", ask);},
updateStatus: function(status){this.set("status", status);},
updatePending: function(pending){this.set("pending", pending);}
})


var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Person;
});
```

if i place the comparator in the backbone.collection it kind of works but i have to explain that.it places all names with a standard image at once and than the images of the contacts appears one at a time in this proces i can see the sort function is working because the images appear in alphabetic order instead of bottom to top but when that is finished the list is not ordered.i hope i am clear enough.

Comment: Does your `Backbone.Collection` have a `comparator` property?

Comment: no it doesnt and i am not that familiar with backbone and i want to learn it from scratch but i am building a program now and i need it for this particilur case.

Comment: Backbone uses `underscore.js` which does the gruntwork you would require for `sorting`. Look up this doc here: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: i update my question above.

Comment: the comparator belongs on the `collection` **not** the `model`

Comment: have you tried `comparator: 'online'` ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add a `comparator` on your persons collection. Backbone collections are automatically sorted when models are added.

```
var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,

    comparator: function(model){
        return model.get('online') ? 0 : 1;
    }
});
```

If user is online, `0` will be returned, if not online, `1` will be returned. `Backbone.Collection.sort()` sorts **ascending** so zeros will appear before ones.

### UPDATE

Based on the comments below, try this:

```
var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    
    model: Person,
    
    comparator: function( model ){
        
        var online =  model.get('online') ? 0 : 1;
        var name = model.get('name');
        
        return  [online, name]; // this will sort by online status first, then person name
    }
    
});
```

Comment: 'var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: Person,
comparator: function( collection ){
   return( collection.get('name'));

}});'
if i use this it is sorting on the name but online is not sorting.

Comment: @RobertIlmer of course "online" is not sorting, your comparator is only sorting by "name". Check my updated answer for how to sort by online status first, then person name

Comment: thanks for your effort kevin but it is only sorting on names, maybe its not possible or i have to do another approach maybe seperate div's for on and offline but i think that the online comes visible in the offline div to.

Comment: well I know it's possible, I do it all the time ;)
Maybe `.get('online')` is returning nothing

Comment: ok so if online is return nothing how come that this.online() works.

Comment: i know online is not sorting but isn't the name sort override the online.even when i use only online i don't get my online contacts first,anyone have an idea?

Comment: i find what the problem is but no solution.all the contacts return false while there are contacts online (true).